# Visual Studio - Not all debugging controls enabled

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

So I am using Visual Studio 2010 and developing a C# .Net Forms Application.  I am at the portion of my code where I am using Delegates and I require the ability to "Step-In" to my code and to "Step-Out" of my code.  Currently, the only option that I have enabled is "Step-Over", which is quite limited.  Here is the list of things that I have tried to re-enable "Step-In" and "Step Out":

- F-10 is tied to Step-Over
- F-11 is also tied to Step-Over
- Adding and Removing Buttons only has the option to remove the Step-Over Button.
- I have looked at the debugging options and have not located the option for enabling additional debugging controls.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I have tried to Google this, but have not found anything (I may not be searching for the right terms)

[Here is a picture of what I am experiencing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h1zT.png) Thank you for your help.

Comment: quick guess: could it have to do with the version of Visual Studio you are using? I remember that the free Express version has some limitation in terms of debugging...

Comment: Nope, I have the ultimate version, so I don't believe it is that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resetting your UI might be advisable.  If you didn't make a lot of customizations then use Tools + Options, Import/Export, Reset.

If that's too much pain then you can repair the command bar.  Tools + Customize, Commands tab.  Select the Toolbar Radio button and pick "Debug".  Use Add Command to add the missing commands back.

Comment: So I want to add to this that you want to reset, but you need to reset it from "C# development settings" to "General Development Settings" and then reset.  Also, to do this, you need to do the following:
Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings and then choose "General Development Settings".  Since you gave me the idea, if you clean up your explanation, I will give you the Approved Answer.  Thanks for your help, it means a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

When you start dealing with asynchronous calls and deferred code, debugging gets trickier. Some times you can manually set a debugger break and allow the JIT to "catch up" (extension methods are a great example). With others, you have to set the breakpoint in the delegated method.

The issue with the later is you have to isolate running the code, as you may delegate back to that method numerous times and you want to catch the correct run (reason to try to step in).

Without seeing exactly what you are doing, all I can give are thought hints.